# IIS 6.1 - Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm having a strange problem with one of my sites in IIS 6.1. All of the other sites are running fine, however this one is currently producing an error "Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue" for nearly every request on a subdirectory (the site homepage seems to load fine).

Has anyone seen this kind of issue? I'm completely at a loss :-(

OK more information from the event viewer:

W3WP.exe seems to be crashing every minute or so:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.17929, time stamp: 0x4ffa59b1
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00000000000afcdb
Faulting process id: 0x2d24
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce4812c6369480
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 48aeb9b0-b406-11e2-ae2a-020053dee25a
```

Comment: Key here is it only happens in some places, see this post: Anytime a file is changed in the application folder, this can trigger an recycle of an application pool. Antivirus real-time monitors are notorious for this, but there is actually quite a large list of potential offenders. http://serverfault.com/questions/227648/iis-worker-process-recycle-without-killing-w3wp